# How to create ARM GCC makefile for a project that includes freeRTOS and libraries?

Tags: gcc, makefile, stm32, freertos

I am working on a project which uses STM32L053 nucleo board.

I need to create a project for STM32L053, with freeRTOS and STM's STM32CubeL0 libraries. I have FreeRTOS port ready for implementation.

But I don't know how to add this freeRTOS and libraries to my project.

Answer (score 3):

Its always best to start with an existing project, then adapt that.  If you don't have a suitable existing project then I suggest:

1) Create a makefile that builds a simple hello world style application for your hardware - without adding in the FreeRTOS source files yet.

2) Ensure your project builds and runs as expected.  That will give you a known good starting point before you add in more source code.

3) Add the FreeRTOS source files to your project.  You will find information on the files that are needed, and the include paths that must be set, on the following page: http://www.freertos.org/Creating-a-new-FreeRTOS-project.html .  The port layer files you need are in the FreeRTOS/source/portable/gcc/ARM_CM0 directory (assuming this is a Cortex-M0 part?).

4) You will need a FreeRTOSConfig.h file.  The one used by the official FreeRTOS [STM32F051](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-for-STM32F051-Cortex-M0-IAR.html) demo will probably be a good starting point.

5) Make sure the project builds, and you can still run the hello world application.

6) Now create your FreeRTOS tasks - here is a good place to start: http://www.freertos.org/Hardware-independent-RTOS-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at PolyMCU: https://github.com/labapart/polymcu

PolyMCU is an open-source firmware framework. It is based on CMake, so you can build on any OS (Windows/Linux/MacOS).
PolyMCU uses vendor SDKs (such as ST's STM32Cube).

There are few examples (including one for FreeRTOS and CMSIS RTOS) https://github.com/labapart/polymcu/tree/master/Application/Examples that you can duplicate to quickly start.